# Missing shared library libunistring.so.2 while setting up NRF Connect SDK

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, zephyr-rtos, nordic-semi

While following '[Installing the nRF Connect SDK](https://developer.nordicsemi.com/nRF_Connect_SDK/doc/latest/nrf/installation/install_ncs.html)' I ran into below issue. I have set-up Zephyr SDK 0.16.1, and I've installed all the basic requirements in the installation guide.:

```
jwielink@ConnectON:~/ncs> nrfutil toolchain-manager launch --shell

Initializing shell environment!

bash-5.2$ west init -m https://github.com/nrfconnect/sdk-nrf --mr v2.5.1
=== Initializing in /home/jwielink/ncs
--- Cloning manifest repository from https://github.com/nrfconnect/sdk-nrf, rev. v2.5.1
Cloning into '/home/jwielink/ncs/.west/manifest-tmp'...
/home/jwielink/ncs/toolchains/7795df4459/usr/local/libexec/git-core/git-remote-https: error while loading shared libraries: libunistring.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
FATAL ERROR: command exited with status 128: git clone --branch v2.5.1 https://github.com/nrfconnect/sdk-nrf /home/jwielink/ncs/.west/manifest-tmp
bash-5.2$
```

I'm on OpenSUSE Tumbleweed.

I've attempted to resolve it by adding the library to my LD_LIBRARY_PATH, to no avail:

```
Initializing shell environment!

bash-5.2$ sudo find / -name libunistring.so.2
find: File system loop detected; ‘/.snapshots/1/snapshot’ is part of the same file system loop as ‘/’.
/home/jwielink/zephyr-sdk-0.16.1/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/lib/libunistring.so.2
find: ‘/run/user/1000/doc’: Permission denied
find: ‘/run/user/1000/gvfs’: Permission denied
bash-5.2$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/home/jwielink/ncs/toolchains/7795df4459/usr/lib:/home/jwielink/ncs/toolchains/7795df4459/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/home/jwielink/ncs/toolchains/7795df4459/usr/local/lib:/home/jwielink/.nrfutil/lib/nrfutil-toolchain-manager:/usr/local/lib:/home/jwielink/zephyr-sdk-0.16.1/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/lib/libunistring.so.2
bash-5.2$
```

Still running into the same issue.

Edit: Worked-around by not using the tool-manager shell, but if anyone happens to know why this is happening, I’d still be interested in knowing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I'm not sure what is going on.

But I've just decided to not use the toolchain-manager:

```
source ~/zephyrproject/.venv/bin/activate
rm -r .west
west init -m https://github.com/nrfconnect/sdk-nrf --mr v2.5.1
```

For anyone who hasn't set-up the Zephyr project yet:
https://docs.zephyrproject.org/latest/develop/getting_started/index.html